# Spring Integration - ClassNotFoundException in Websphere

Tags: java, spring, websphere, classloader, spring-integration

A spring integration project worked correctly locally in Eclipse / Tomcat.

When deploying to Websphere, I get classloader issues from the Spring Integration classes:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.integration.message.ErrorMessage
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler.handleError(MessagePublishingErrorHandler.java:83)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.DelegatingWork.run(DelegatingWork.java:61)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1178)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.go(WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.java:199)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.CJWorkItemImpl.run(CJWorkItemImpl.java:236)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1700)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.message.ErrorMessage
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:204)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:699)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:678)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:119)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:661)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:598)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:661)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:661)
    ... 7 more
```

It looks like the application is actually working, but outputting these errors, but I don't like the idea of it.

All spring jars are in my classpath. I tried changing the classloader to Parent_Last but got some other issues

Are there any additional settings needed for Websphere?

Comment: May be you have placed the Spring Integration related jar file in a Tomcat specific lib directory instead of placing it in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: No, it is a Maven project and all jars are handled by maven.

Comment: Have you switched 'Single class loader' for your application?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, what you are describing makes no sense; `ErrorMessage` is in the same jar as `MessagePublishingErrorHandler`.

So, that means it is likely a classloader issue. Best guess is you are loading `ErrorMessage` from two different jars in different classloaders.

Run the JVM with `-verbose` and check which classes are being loaded from which jars.

Comment: so I see that MessagePublishingErrorHandler is loaded from spring-integration-core-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar, and I don't see ErrorMessage at all, even though it's in that jar. Not sure what to make of it.

Comment: Me neither; I've never seen anything like it. The hierarchy of classloaders does look rather chaotic - with the call stack having 10 classloaders in it! You may need to run in a debugger and look at the URL(s) the topmost classloader is trying to load from. Also, to figure out which classloader loaded the `MPEH`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with [ClassLoader order](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Fcrun_classload.html) for your application from WAS console.